# How to RBL block forwarded email in postfix?

Tags: postfix, email-server, mail-forwarding, rbl

I have RBL blocking successfully configured in postfix, using `reject_rbl_client` in the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` section.

However, I use a mail forwarding service through which I receive some spam emails.
These emails are not rejected by the RBL filter, as the offending IP address is not the sender (the email forwarder).

The original IP address that sent the spam is in a `Received` email header:

`Received: from uni-tec.su ([195.182.132.228])`

Can postfix be configured to perform an RBL check on the IP address in this "Received" email header?

Comment: sounds dangerous, many blacklists include residential subnets, often included in these headers

Comment: You'll probably need a milter to dig through the message headers. This might be better done by a anti-spam engine that scores such headers with other indications of spaminess. Agree with Jacob that RBL choice will need to be done with care.